# Creating a formula editor in Silverlight 5

Tags: c#, silverlight, formula-editor

Working with (as of now) Silverlight 5, I am trying to develop a screen where I can setup an object formula to do addition/subtraction/multiplication/division... a simple "calculator" application, but specific to a business domain.

What I am trying to do is to show the order of operations, but haven't been able to find any great samples that can take me down this road.  Has anyone found such a beast, and if so, can they show what they've found?

to give further of what I want to do, at the end, take a look at the DevExpress Filter editor for their [grid](http://demos.devexpress.com/DemoCenter/Silverlight/?GridDemo#Multi_View)  product.

Comment: I'm thinking that I can do it with a few well constructed user controls, and will update this after I'm finished.  I think it's going to be more simplistic than what it feels.